# Unable to compare two dates in android

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I want to compare two dates to categories Browser History...
I have seen too many posts but didn't get any helpful,

My code is as :

```
 private static String calculateDate()
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -10);
    return simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
}
private static String today()
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,0);
    return simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
}

public void getBHistory()
{
    long startdates = 0;
    long enddates = 0;
    Date endDate = null;
    Date startDate=null;

    try
    {
        startDate = (Date)new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .parse(calculateDate());
        endDate = (Date)new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .parse(today());
        startdates = startDate.getTime();
        enddates = endDate.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
    String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0" + " AND "
            + Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    Cursor mCur = m_oContext.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, sel,
            new String[]{
                    "" + startdates, "" + enddates
            }, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    String title = "";
    String date_time = "";
    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (!mCur.isAfterLast())
        {

            title = mCur.getString(mCur
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            date_time = mCur.getString(mCur
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE));
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String curDate=simpleDate.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(date_time)));

            Toast.makeText(m_oContext,"History Time : "+curDate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(m_oContext,"Limit Time : "+calculateDate(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //TODO: Compare these two dates here

            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }

}
```

I want to do if the History date is earlier than ten days ago then notify the user.
Any kind of help will be appreciated ,thank you.

Comment: Glad to see you joining Stack Overflow. When posting here, make your Question laser-focused on one narrow issue. Rather than paste all your real code, strip it down to the absolute minimum to demonstrate your issue. Make a [MCVE – Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar is comparable so you can just use compare to. I would make curDate a calendar. Then `(curDate.compareTo(calculatedDate) < 0)` will be true if curDate is earlier than calculatedDate which you've set to ten days before today.

Comment: Calendar cal1  = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal2= Calendar.getInstance();
                try
                {
                    cal1.setTime(simpleDate.parse(curDate));
                } catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    try
                {
                    cal2.setTime(simpleDate.parse(calculateDate()));
} catch (ParseException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 if(cal1.compareTo(cal2)<0)
   {Toast.makeText(m_oContext,"Notify",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Comment: What do you mean by nothing is happening? If your date is equal or after calculated date the if statement will be false.

Comment: the dates are before the calculated date

Comment: Also just as a tip since you already have the calendar objects I would use them instead of having your methods return strings. Then you can avoid the extra parse step to get the calendar objects.

Comment: Ok can you print the two dates you are comparing to the log. That way we can see what's happening.

Comment: you were right .... Unfortunately I was comparing and checking the history since same date  that's why it was not returning true

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Boolean alertUser = 
    LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-02" )
             .isBefore( 
                 LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” ) )
                          .minusDays( 10 ) 
             ) ;
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Time zone

Your code ignores the crucial issue of time zone in determining a date such as “today”.

## Example code

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Your input strings are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate target = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-02" );
```

You say the boundary is ten days ago. Use the `plus` or `minus` methods to determine future/past dates.

```
LocalDate tenDaysAgo = today.minusDays( 10 );
```

Compare using `compareTo`, `equals`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean alertUser = target.isBefore( tenDaysAgo );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use
    before()
    Or
    after()
to compare your calculated date with today's date

Comment: Calendar cal1  = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal2= Calendar.getInstance();
                try
                {
                    cal1.setTime(simpleDate.parse(curDate));
                    cal2.setTime(simpleDate.parse(calculateDate()));
                } catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(cal1.before(cal2))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(m_oContext,"Notify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

Comment: Please refer this post if get any help please update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537535/check-date-with-todays-date

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isHDateEarlier(String historyDate){

      String[] historySplitStrings= historyDate.split("-");
      String[] tenDaysEarlierStrings = calculateDate().split("-");

      int historyYear = Integer.parseInt(historySplitStrings[0]);
      int daysYear = Integer.parseInt(tenDaysEarlierStrings [0]);
      int historyMonth = Integer.parseInt(historySplitStrings[1]);
      int daysMonth = Integer.parseInt(tenDaysEarlierStrings [1]);
      int historyDay = Integer.parseInt(historySplitStrings[2]);
      int daysDay = Integer.parseInt(tenDaysEarlierStrings [2]);


if(historyYear  < daysYear ){//check year
      return true;
}

    if(historyMonth  < daysMonth  &&    
          historyYear   <= daysYear ){//check month
          return true;
    }



  if(historyDay < daysDay && 
        historyYear <= daysYear && 
        historyMonth <= daysMonth){//check day
          return true;
  }

return false;
}
```

Just call :

```
isHDateEarlier(curDate);
```

Comment: how can we apply < operator to a string

Comment: @sam sorry my mistake, forgot to parse them as int.

Comment: In which case the date fall before the curDate

Comment: This function verifies if the date you provide as parameter is earlier than 10 days ago. It's working fine, it should return true for "2016-09-17"  as example.

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with comparing dates a week ago, and searched for answers and this helped me: [Find nearest date from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884644/find-nearest-date-from-a-list). - The last answer talks about `NavigableSet<>`

Try using `NavigableSet<Date>` such as `TreeSet<>` and put your dates in the list. 
Than compare with `lower` or `higher`

Comment: This is very superfluous for comparing dates. This would be more useful if you are trying to do a search for the closest date to a given date.